# PHP code not working,not connecting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I'm trying to get simple form data added to mysql database via php.

This is my php code..

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','sahunihal123321','aliendatabase')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query="INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name,last_name,when_it_happened,how_long, " .
"how_many,alien_description,what_they_did,fang_spotted,other,email)" .
"VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$when_it_happened','$how_long','$how_many', " .
"'$alien_description','$what_they_did','$fang_spotted','$other','$email')";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
or die('Error querying database.');
mysqli_close($dbc);


  echo 'Thanks for submitting the form.<br />';
  echo 'You were abducted ' . $when_it_happened;
  echo ' and were gone for ' . $how_long . '<br />';
  echo 'Number of aliens: ' . $how_many . '<br />';
  echo 'Describe them: ' . $alien_description . '<br />';
  echo 'The aliens did this: ' . $what_they_did . '<br />';
  echo 'Was Fang there? ' . $fang_spotted . '<br />';
  echo 'Other comments: ' . $other . '<br />';
  echo 'Your email address is ' . $email;


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Nothing is being displayed.

So ,Something going wrong in the connect stage,
Im working on a local system not a server , and no problem with the form

I go to access my mysql database ,this is what i see

```
nsnihalsahu@nsnihalsahu-home:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 38
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW DATABASES
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| aliendatabase      |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE aliendatabase
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_aliendatabase |
+-------------------------+
| aliens_abduction        |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM aliens_abduction;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try connect the same using hostname as `localhost` if you hosted files and  database in same server or in local instance. The reson may `nsnihalsahu-home`have no enough priviellges to establish the connection with database, you need to provide credentails for that hostname to establish the hostname. `grant all privileges`

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','sahunihal123321','aliendatabase') 
      or die("Error " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

To more about privileges: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html

Can you please share`mysqli_error` information, so that I can help you much better.

Comment: This, and also please make sure you sanitise your input: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: It's working just the same ,no difference

Answer (score 1):

I copied this from php.net, try to use this instead to connect to your db:

For remote:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

For localhost:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

Comment: Same no difference ,everything is same

Comment: I see, do you get any error msg?

Comment: No ,I edited my question,Please refer to that

Comment: vote up  for simple script to check connection

Answer (score 0):

your databse connection close code `mysqli_close($dbc)` in

```
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
or die('Error querying database.');
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

is not conditional i.e. i.e. it will execute anyways and thus resulting in the closing of your databse connection.same here

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

remove `mysqli_close($dbc)` from the **middle of the code** or **make it conditional**.it should only execute when there is some error.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my error logs, since I was doing it in UBUNTU 13.10,every third quote became fancy .
It was a PHP parse error.Used a good code editore ,It just went away,personally ,I'm moving to Debian.